# « Au titre de leur appartenance » comparé à « en tant que parties intégrantes » : nuances, impact des prépositions ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, locutions, comparaison-de-langues, connotation

On s'intéresse au texte du préambule de certains instruments juridiques canadiens où l'on traite de leur [histoire](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/Const/page-1.html#h-2) et des [valeurs](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/Const/page-15.html#h-46) qui les sous-tendent<sup>1</sup> :

> qu’il [le gouvernement fédéral] s’est engagé à favoriser l’épanouissement des minorités
>   francophones et anglophones, *au titre de leur appartenance aux deux
>   collectivités de langue officielle*, et à appuyer leur développement et
>   à promouvoir la pleine reconnaissance et l’usage du français et de
>   l’anglais dans la société canadienne;
>
> ---
>
> AND WHEREAS the Government of Canada is committed to enhancing the
>   vitality and supporting the development of English and French
>   linguistic minority communities, *[as](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/as) an [integral](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/integral) part of the two
>   official language communities of Canada*, and to fostering full
>   recognition and use of English and French in Canadian society;
>
> [ [*Loi sur les langues officielles*](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/lois/O-3.01/TexteComplet.html) (Canada), L.R.C. (1985), ch.
>   31, extrait du préambule, je souligne ]

Je sais qu'on a aussi en français la [*partie intégrante*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/integral/589261?q=integral%20part#852451) ou les *parties intégrantes*, soit l'« élément constituant essentiel d'un tout » ([Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/int%C3%A9grant/43530?q=int%C3%A9grante#43451)) ou les « partie(s), élément(s) qui, bien que ne constituant pas l'essence, est/sont nécessaire(s) pour l'intégrité du tout » ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/int%C3%A9grante)). D'autre part on a la locution prépositive [*au titre de*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/au_titre_de) pour *selon/en vertu de* et l'[*appartenance*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appartenance), le fait d'[*appartenir*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/appartenir), « faire partie organique d'un ensemble » (TLFi).

- Dans la citation provenant du préambule, quelle serait la nuance de sens entre *au titre de leur appartenance* et *comme/en tant que parties intégrantes* ; le premier est-il d'un registre plus soutenu ; laquelle ou lesquelles des prépositions *selon/en vertu/en tant que/comme* etc. fonctionne le mieux comme synonyme de *au titre de* ici ?
- La locution prépositive (construite avec [*titre*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/titre)) change-t-elle la sémantique ou a-t-elle un effet sur le nom *appartenance*, résulte-t-il de leur collocation l'idée du caractère essentiel ou la même qualité que celle de la *partie intégrante* ?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Et qui diffèrent à mon avis de celles de ceux qui en attaquent les fondements aujourd'hui. En effet, dans un [contexte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bas-Canada) [historique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B4pital_Montfort#SOS_Montfort) particulier au Canada, s'appuyant sur l'opportunisme et arguant l'[utilité](https://www.fin.gov.on.ca/fallstatement/2018/chapter-1a.html#section-3), ceux-ci ont cautionné le [démantèlement](https://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/politique/201811/20/01-5204954-coupes-en-francophonie-ottawa-annonce-des-mesures.php?utm_categorieinterne=trafficdrivers&utm_contenuinterne=cyberpresse_B13b_politique-canadienne_560_section_POS4) de services aux francophones de l'Ontario affectant directement leurs droits et tentent de saper [en douce](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/chroniques/patrick-lagace/201811/19/01-5204844-ils-sen-fichent.php) l'essor de cette [minorité](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco-Ontariens) (ou d'autres [ailleurs](https://www.acadienouvelle.com/editoriaux/2013/10/17/prix-lintolerance/) au [pays](https://www.lapresse.ca/debats/editoriaux/paul-journet/201811/16/01-5204580-speak-ontarien-please.php)), puis la droite a ensuite refusé à l'échelle nationale de [dénoncer](http://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/42-1/chambre/seance-353/debats#Int-10376594) un tel geste, reléguant à des questions provinciales ou à une [blague](http://www.noscommunes.ca/DocumentViewer/fr/42-1/chambre/seance-353/debats#Int-10376603) sur le budget le fait français en Ontario et plus généralement au Canada.</sub>.

Comment: Si on s'intéresse au cadre juridique dans lequel s'inscrit la loi en question etc., on peut consulter ce [lien](https://www.clo-ocol.gc.ca/fr/droits_linguistiques/loi). La situation linguistique au Canada est la [suivante](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langues_au_Canada), il y au dernier recensement 7 054 975 de Canadiens qui ont comme langue maternelle le français, dont 6 102 210 se trouvent au Québec (donc il y a seulement un million de francophones hors Québec au Canada), 18 858 980 pour qui c'est l'anglais et 6 567 685 pour qui c'est une autre langue : total 33 121 175 (2011). Merci !

Answer (score 2):

Ce qui suit ne représente que mon opinion :

Je ne crois pas que *en tant que parties intégrantes* soit une alternative possible à *au titre de leur appartenance* dans la traduction d'*integral part*.

Je crois que l'alternative serait bien plutôt : *en tant que constituant **à part entière***.

---

Pour ce qui est de *au titre de*, je crois que l'on souligne mieux le coté ***de droit*** (qui me semble très important à souligner ici) qu'on ne le ferait en utilisant toute autre alternative.

(*au titre* sous-entend un droit,
*En raison* sous-entend une logique,
*en vertu* sous-entend un pouvoir,
*en tant* *et alliis* ne sous-entendant... rien du tout.)

---

En finale, écrire *"**au titre de leur appartenance aux deux collectivités**"* ou, l'alternative que je suggère plus haut : *"**au titre de composantes à part entière des deux collectivités***" ne fait que reconnaître un fait sociologico-linguistique, une relation d'inclusion, et à l'établir de plein droit.

Quand *"**en tant que parties intégrantes des deux collectivités**"* reviendrait à reconnaître à chacune des minorités une singularité, une spécificité constitutive de la collectivité, spécificité sans laquelle, le fonctionnement, le développement voire la survie seraient compromis.

Pour une illustration encore plus dégagée de toute sensibilité humaine sur le propos, je dirais :

- 5 est un nombre réel en raison de son appartenance à l'ensemble des nombres entiers

Mais

- 5 fait partie intégrante de la suite des nombres premiers. (Si on enlève le 5 de la suite de nombres, celle-ci ne correspond plus à la suite des nombres premiers)

Comment: @Montéedelait : Merci de votre éclairage qui me fait réaliser que j'avais trop probablement sur-lu le texte constitutionnel, qui, pour moi ne s'adressait pas aux membres d'une des deux communautés favorisées. Vous parlez du Saskatchewan... Pour moi, ce texte s'adressait à l'Algonquin mis dans l'obligation d'apprendre L'anglais ou, voire l'anglais et le français. Ou, plus généralement; adressé à toutes les minorités indigènes mises en devoir d'apprendre la langue de minorités allogènes. (ce qui n'est, à ce que j'ai pu constater pas vraiment passé comme une lettre à la poste).

Comment: @Montéedelait : J'avais sur-lu donc, merci encore de m'avoir arrêté, je corrige la réponse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86119/discussion-between-nonobstant-fascisme-and-montee-de-lait).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86121/discussion-on-answer-by-acoswt--au-titre-de-leur-appartenance--compare-a--en).